# Can I Echo php inside jQuery Array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I am working on a project and I can't seem to figure the best way to handle this. I am using jQuery Supersized and options framework to build a theme. I have everything working for the slider options except for the images. Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.supersized({
            // Functionality
            slideshow: 1, // Slideshow on/off
            autoplay: <? php echo of_get_option('autoplay', '1'); ?> , // Slideshow starts playing automatically
            start_slide: 1, // Start slide (0 is random)
            stop_loop: 0, // Pauses slideshow on last slide
            random: <? php echo of_get_option('random', '0'); ?> , // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
            slide_interval: <? php echo of_get_option('slide_interval', '3000'); ?> , // Length between transitions
            transition: <? php echo of_get_option('transitions', '1'); ?> , // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed: 1000, // Speed of transition
            new_window: 1, // Image links open in new window/tab
            pause_hover: 0, // Pause slideshow on hover
            keyboard_nav: 1, // Keyboard navigation on/off
            performance: 1, // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
            image_protect: <? php echo of_get_option('protect_images', '1'); ?> , // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

            // Size & Position                         
            min_width: 0, // Min width allowed (in pixels)
            min_height: 0, // Min height allowed (in pixels)
            vertical_center: 1, // Vertically center background
            horizontal_center: <? php echo of_get_option('horizontal_center', '1'); ?> , // Horizontally center background
            fit_always: <? php echo of_get_option('always_fit', '0'); ?> , // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
            fit_portrait: 1, // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
            fit_landscape: 0, // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

            // Components                           
            slide_links: 'blank', // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            thumb_links: 1, // Individual thumb links for each slide
            thumbnail_navigation: 0, // Thumbnail navigation
            slides: [ // Slideshow Images
            {
                image: '<?php echo of_get_option("image_1"); ?>'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-2.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-2.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-3.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-3.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-1.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-1.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'
            }, {
                image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-3.jpg',
                title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden',
                thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-3.jpg',
                url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'
            }],

            // Theme Options               
            progress_bar: 1, // Timer for each slide                            
            mouse_scrub: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

All my settings work s intended except images. The funny thing is that when I view the source the it shows the link to the image just like the ones that are manually put in. 
I have tried to put the data in an array and then display the output dynamically and still no go. I get the same result in the source. `{image :'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg'},`

Why won't it load the image from an echo but it shows that it's there in the source.

Comment: maybe you need to add a call to urlencode or even json_encode in the php?

Comment: I tried json_encode but I'm not sure I even did it right.

Comment: You are sure it's the echo that's the problem? If you hard code the url for the image, is it showing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create json in clear php code, and then include that json into javascript expression.

Code will be better.

You have less chances to do mistakes (with quotes for example).

Answer (score 1):

Be VERY VERY VERY careful doing this. You're directly outputting into a Javascript code block, which means that **ALL** of your output has to create syntactically valid JS code. A single mis-placed `'` can kill the entire script block.

For security's sake, you should be doing all your output via json _encode() which guarantees that you won't introduce syntax errors.

e.g.

```
random: <?php echo json_encode(of_get_option('random', '0')); ?> , // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
```

Consider a case like:

```
<?php
$name = "Miles O'Brien";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var name = '<?php echo $name; ';
</script>
```

You'd end up producing:

```
var name = 'Miles O'Brien';
                   ^--- syntax error, terminating the string early.
```

Comment: When I do this it out puts the values but it won't accept it. I tried to just wrap the integer like this `slideshow: "1",` it doesn't work

Comment: `"1"` is a string, not an integer.

Comment: Plus I get this output for the image url `{image : '"http:\/\/localhost\/zomb\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/09\/background1.jpg"'},`

Comment: that looks more like register_globals than anything json_encode would do.

Comment: Then how can I use json_encode when it produces a string and the script uses an integer?

Comment: `<?php echo json_encode(of_get_option("image_1")); ?>`  ==  `{image : '"http:\/\/localhost\/zomb\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/09\/background1.jpg"'},` and register_globals is turned off

Comment: and a straight echo without the json_encode? json is basically javascript - `/` is **NOT** a metacharacter that has to be escaped in strings. either way, it would appear that of_get_option is producing a string, not an integer.

Comment: `{image : 'http:\\localhost\zomb\wp content\uploads\2012\09\background1.jpg'},` This is without json but still nothing shows up. It's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you place quotes either side of the php braces, or else javascript won't receive it as a string. e.g.

```
random                  :   '<?php echo of_get_option('random', '0'); ?>'
```

Comment: True. If you're only dealing with integers then this won't apply.

Comment: Yes Yes, but that's not my question.